# How to search in JSON data with dynamic results

Tags: javascript, json, search

I'm building an eCommerce system using variants and I need a little help on retrieving the JSON data when an option is changed.

I can change code to suit what is needed, but this is what I have so far.

I'm outputting all the options as selects on the page. Once one of those select options are changed, I'm triggering a function to be run. That function gets the selected values of all the options on the page. Bear in mind this is dynamically generated content and can be a different amount of options per product. This is how I get the selected options currently:

```js
  // Check current selected product
  function getSelectedData() {
    // Get selected values
    let selectedValues = new Array();
    document.querySelectorAll('.variant-option').forEach(variantData => {
      // Get variant ID
      variantID = variantData.name.replace('variant_', '');
      // Set selected value
      selectedValues.push({
        id: variantID,
        value: variantData.value
      });
    });
    // Find the value
    console.log(jsonData.variants);
    console.log(selectedValues);
  }
```

And this will return something like so:

```js
array["0": {id "2", value: "19"}, "1": {id "3", value: "21"}]
```

You'll see that I'm also console logging a `jsonData.variants`. Here's an example of what's in there

```
{
    "variants": [{
        "id": 41,
        "name": "5&#39;10&#34;/Black",
        "variant_2": 19,
        "variant_3": 21,
        "var_code": "47016.000",
        "taxable": 1,
        "tax_name": null,
        "tax_rate": null,
        "image_index": 0,
        "quantity": 0.00,
        "price": 29.08
    }, {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "5&#39;10&#34;/Orange",
        "variant_2": 19,
        "variant_3": 24,
        "var_code": "47016.001",
        "taxable": 1,
        "tax_name": null,
        "tax_rate": null,
        "image_index": null,
        "quantity": 0.00,
        "price": 29.08
    }, {
        "id": 43,
        "name": "5&#39;3&#34;/Black",
        "variant_2": 15,
        "variant_3": 21,
        "var_code": "47016.002",
        "taxable": 1,
        "tax_name": null,
        "tax_rate": null,
        "image_index": null,
        "quantity": 0.00,
        "price": 29.08
    }, {
        "id": 44,
        "name": "5&#39;3&#34;/Orange",
        "variant_2": 15,
        "variant_3": 24,
        "var_code": "47016.003",
        "taxable": 1,
        "tax_name": null,
        "tax_rate": null,
        "image_index": null,
        "quantity": 0.00,
        "price": 29.08
    }]
}
```

What I want to be able to do is search this data and find which variant matches the selection. I've been looking into the [find() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), but I'm not entirely sure how to get this to work dynamically.

So on each variant, it outputs something like `variant_x`, where `x` defines the variant ID. So for example, from my JSON data above, there are 2 colours and 2 sizes. If someone changes the selected size I want it to search the JSON data for results matching the 2 selections (`variant_2` and `variant_3`) and return which object from the JSON data is the selected option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up slightly modifying my code to use the [`find()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). I know the code is always going to be output in the same format so changed it as follows:

**jsonData.variants with new `var_values` variable**

```
{
    "variants": [{
        "id": 41,
        "name": "5&#039;10&quot;/Black",
        "variant_2": 19,
        "variant_3": 21,
        "var_values": "19,21",
        "var_code": "47016.000",
        "taxable": 1,
        "tax_name": null,
        "tax_rate": null,
        "image_index": 0,
        "quantity": 0.00,
        "price": 29.08
    }, {
        "id": 72,
        "name": "5&#039;10&quot;/Blue",
        "variant_2": 19,
        "variant_3": 22,
        "var_values": "19,22",
        "var_code": "47016.004",
        "taxable": 1,
        "tax_name": "G.S.T. (15%)",
        "tax_rate": "0,15.0000",
        "image_index": null,
        "quantity": 0.00,
        "price": 38.00
    }, {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "5&#039;10&quot;/Orange",
        "variant_2": 19,
        "variant_3": 24,
        "var_values": "19,24",
        "var_code": "47016.001",
        "taxable": 1,
        "tax_name": null,
        "tax_rate": null,
        "image_index": null,
        "quantity": 0.00,
        "price": 29.08
    }, {
        "id": 43,
        "name": "5&#039;3&quot;/Black",
        "variant_2": 15,
        "variant_3": 21,
        "var_values": "15,21",
        "var_code": "47016.002",
        "taxable": 1,
        "tax_name": null,
        "tax_rate": null,
        "image_index": null,
        "quantity": 0.00,
        "price": 29.08
    }, {
        "id": 44,
        "name": "5&#039;3&quot;/Orange",
        "variant_2": 15,
        "variant_3": 24,
        "var_values": "15,24",
        "var_code": "47016.003",
        "taxable": 1,
        "tax_name": null,
        "tax_rate": null,
        "image_index": null,
        "quantity": 0.00,
        "price": 29.08
    }]
  }
```

**Update search function to match data**

```js
function getSelectedData() {
    // Get selected values
    let selectedValues = '';
    document.querySelectorAll('.variant-option').forEach(variantData => {
      // Get variant ID
      variantID = variantData.name.replace('variant_', '');
      selectedValues += `${variantData.value},`;
    });

    // Remove trailing comma
    selectedValues = selectedValues.trim().replace(/,{1,}$/, '');

    // Find the value
    let variantData = jsonData.variants.find(variant => variant.var_values === selectedValues);

    // Check if match was found
    if (variantData) { ... }
}
```